# flask-sqlalchemy with PostgreSQL enum value retrieved as a list

Tags: python, flask, enums, flask-sqlalchemy

I have the weirdest behavior while using `flask-sqlalchemy`, I have a `User` model and I have an enum with the user role as `userrole`, it has the following values `('vendor', 'vendor_admin', 'admin', 'collector', 'retailer')`, the weird thing is that whenever I query the users I get all the roles as string except the `admin` for some reason it comes as a `list` with the value `admin`.

I've deleted the database and re-migrated everything from scratch but still.

Here is my `User` model:

```
from app import db, ma
from marshmallow_enum import EnumField
import enum
import bcrypt


class UserRoleEnum(enum.Enum):
    admin = 'admin',
    collector = 'collector'
    retailer = 'retailer'
    vendor = 'vendor'
    vendor_admin = 'vendor_admin'


class User(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'users'

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(), nullable=False)
    mobile = db.Column(db.String(), nullable=False, unique=True)
    username = db.Column(db.String(), unique=True, nullable=False)
    password = db.Column(db.TEXT(), nullable=False)
    is_active = db.Column(db.Boolean(), default=False)
    role = db.Column(db.Enum(UserRoleEnum), nullable=False)
    created_on = db.Column(db.DateTime, server_default=db.func.now())
    updated_on = db.Column(db.DateTime, server_default=db.func.now(), server_onupdate=db.func.now())

    # relations

    #related fields
    organization_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('organizations.id'), nullable=True)
    invoices = db.relationship('Invoice', backref='user')

    def __init__(
            self,
            name,
            username,
            mobile,
            password,
            role,
            is_active,
            organization_id = None
    ):
        self.name = name
        self.username = username
        self.mobile = mobile
        self.role = role
        self.is_active = is_active
        self.organization_id = organization_id
        self.password = bcrypt.hashpw(password.encode('utf-8'), bcrypt.gensalt()).decode()

    def __repr__(self):
        return "<id %s>" % self.id


class UserSchema(ma.SQLAlchemyAutoSchema):
    role = EnumField(UserRoleEnum, by_value=True)
    class Meta:
        exclude = ['password']
        model = User
        load_instance = True
```

Here is the login endpoint:

```
@auth_routes.route('login', methods=['POST'])
def login():
    payload = request.json

    if not payload.get('mobile') or not payload.get('password'):
        return "Mobile and Password are required", 400

    user = User.query.filter_by(mobile=payload.get('mobile')).first()

    if not user:
        return "User not found", 404

    if bcrypt.checkpw(payload.get('password').encode('utf-8'), user.password.encode('utf-8')):

        organization = None

        if user.organization_id:
            organization = OrganizationSchema().dump(Organization.query.get(user.organization_id)).data

        token = create_access_token(identity={
            'id': user.id,
            'username': user.username,
            'mobile': user.mobile,
            'is_active': user.is_active,
            'role': user.role.value,
            'organization': organization
        }, expires_delta=timedelta(days=0) + timedelta(days=365))
        return {
            "token": token
        }
    else:
        return "Error on password"
```

Here is an example from the terminal:

```
>>> user = User.query.get(1)
>>> user.role.value
('admin',)
>>> user = User.query.get(2)
>>> user.role.value
'vendor_admin'
```

Comment: Note that we prefer a technical style of writing here. We gently discourage greetings, hope-you-can-helps, thanks, advance thanks, notes of appreciation, regards, kind regards, signatures, please-can-you-helps, chatty material and abbreviated txtspk, pleading, how long you've been stuck, voting advice, meta commentary, etc. Just explain your problem, and show what you've tried, what you expected, and what actually happened.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a trailing comma so admin value is a tuple

```
class UserRoleEnum(enum.Enum):
    admin = 'admin',
```

Remove it and all will be fine

Comment: Thanks, didn't notice the typo